# How to set up where to store data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

My `C:\` drive has a size of 99GB and my `D:\` drive has a size of 2TB

Here comes the problem: where does SQL Server store data in the database? Can I control it?

Actually, my `C:\` has been full of data now..... and I don't know how to deal with it.

I want to configure SQL Server right so that I can store data on `D:\`

Thank you very much.

Comment: If your drive is filling up, make sure you are backing up your transaction log and cycling your backups, or that your db is set in simple recovery mode.

Comment: please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856467/sql-server-change-data-and-log-path-of-existing-database

Answer (score 2):

You could also control it with:

- detaching the database in SQL management studio
- move the *.mdf and *.ldf file to the location you desire (C:/ or D:/)
- reattaching the database by selecting the new path.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your database and select properties. In the file tab you find your database .mdf and .ndf files path.
You can use detach and attach to move your files.
Also you can modify new filegroup and add objects to that filegroup to have additional space.